# Private variable naming convention in official Angular 2 http tutorial

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand how private variable is named in the official Angular 2 [http tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data)

Under the section linked above is a file called `app/toh/hero.service.ts`, which (mainly) is this:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  private _heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';

  getHeroes () {
    return this.http.get(this._heroesUrl)
                    .map(res => <Hero[]> res.json().data)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError (error: Response) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

There is a private variable `_heroesUrl`. Ok, so there exists a convention to start private variables and methods with underscore.

But then why is it not used an underscore also for `private http` and `private handleError`? Is it just a "typo" or is it a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a typo. For TS this is not enforced, it's just a convention. Within the Angular2 codebase this is used consistently to allow transpilation to Dart where the `_` is not only a convention but a replacement for the `private` keyword (which doesn't exist in Dart)

Comment: In Angular2 styles guide : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html doesn't say anything about this convention for private members. I used it all over my app, but now I consider to remove it. I think it helps just a bit, but the code looks a bit weird ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There was an discussion recently and most were against using underlines in TypeScript. The official style rule is now to not use it. The Angular code base itself uses it for the reason mentioned in my answer (Dart transpilation).